# Dynamic Column Update PLSQL trigger

Tags: plsql, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables **A** and **B**

In table **A** there are two columns **"Sequence Number"** and **"Content"**.

```
Name    Null? Type         
------- ----- ------------ 
SEQ_NO        NUMBER(6)    
CONTENT       VARCHAR2(20)
```

In table **B** there are multiple statement columns like **"Stmt_1", "Stmt_2", "Stmt_3" etc.**

```
Name   Null? Type         
------ ----- ------------ 
STMT_1       VARCHAR2(20) 
STMT_2       VARCHAR2(20) 
STMT_3       VARCHAR2(20) 
STMT_4       VARCHAR2(20)
```

I want to create a **trigger** on table **A** such that **after every insert on table A**, according to the **"Sequence Number"** value the corresponding column in table **B** gets **updated**.

***For example:*** If table **A** has **"Sequence Number" = 1** , then **"Stmt_1"** of table **B** gets updated to the value of **"Content"** column in table **A**.

If table **A** is given as

```
"SEQ_NO"    "CONTENT"
1   "This is Content"
```

Then Table **B** should look like:

```
"STMT_1","STMT_2","STMT_3","STMT_4"
"This is Content","","",""
```

My approach is as follows:

```
create or replace trigger TestTrig
after insert on A for each row
begin
    declare
    temp varchar2(6);
    begin
        temp := concat("Stmt_",:new.seq_no);
        update B
        set temp = :new.content;
    end;
end;
```

But I am getting an error in the update statement.

**Does anyone know how to approach this problem?**

Comment: Try to learn the dynamic PL SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use dynamic SQL (and `'` is for string literals, `"` is for identifiers):

```sql
create or replace trigger TestTrig
  after insert on A
  for each row
DECLARE
  temp varchar2(11);
begin
  temp := 'Stmt_' || TO_CHAR(:new.seq_no, 'FM999990');
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE B SET ' || temp || ' = :1' USING :NEW.content;
end;
/
```

---

You probably want to handle errors when `seq_no` is input as `5` and there is no `STMT_5` column in table `B`:

```sql
create or replace trigger TestTrig
  after insert on A
  for each row
DECLARE
  temp varchar2(11);
  INVALID_IDENTIFIER EXCEPTION;
  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(INVALID_IDENTIFIER, -904);
begin
  temp := 'Stmt_' || TO_CHAR(:new.seq_no, 'FM999990');
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'UPDATE B SET ' || temp || ' = :1' USING :NEW.content;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN INVALID_IDENTIFIER THEN
    NULL;
end;
/
```

---

#### However

I would suggest that you do not want a table `B` or a trigger to update it and you want a `VIEW` instead:

```sql
CREATE VIEW B (stmt_1, stmt2, stmt3, stmt4) AS
SELECT *
FROM   A
PIVOT (
  MAX(content)
  FOR seq_no IN (
    1 AS stmt_1,
    2 AS stmt_2,
    3 AS stmt_3,
    4 AS stmt_4
  )
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/397Sh2nr);

Comment: The motive is to update table B with the help of table A. I don't think view will help me there. you mentioned dynamic plsql here. 
I am a noob, Can you mention any source where I can learn it?

Comment: @SandeepChander If you have a view then you do not need to update `B` as `B` will automatically be generated from table `A` and will always be up-to-date. However, since you have not included details of how you are using `A` and `B`  then you should decide, based on your use-cases, which solution is more appropriate.

Comment: Ok thanks, I also requested for a learning source, would you be so kind to help me with that as well?

Comment: @SandeepChander No. Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more is off-topic on StackOverflow as it is likely to lead to opinion-based answers. But is it easy to search the internet for "oracle execute immediate" which should return Oracle's documentation.